# Expected number of different colours when randomly selecting n balls from a box of mixed colours

Tags: probability, expected-value

I'm not a mathematician but I have some applied statistics background. I have some data for which I want to calculate some expected values.

I have a box with 20 balls of 5 different colours, of varying frequencies (say 1 red, 2 blue, 4 yellow, 6 orange, 7 green). If I select 1 ball, I will have one colour. I'd like to know how many colours I should expect to have, on average, as I then pick out successive balls, i.e. how many colours would I expect to have if I pick another ball, and another ball, all the way up to 20 when I will obviously have 5 colours. I imagine the values from 2 - 19 will be fractions, as this is average expectation.

Either this has a really simple answer, or it's really complicated. I'd like to be able to generalise the solution to a box of any number of balls with any number of colours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By linearity of expectation, the expected number of colours is the sum of the probabilities of each colour being selected. If you have $n_i$ balls of colour $i$ and a total of $n$ balls and you draw $k$ balls without replacement, this is

$$
\sum_i\left(1-\frac{\binom{n-n_i}k}{\binom nk}\right)\;.
$$

Comment: (I wonder whether this falsifies your prediction that it's either a really simple answer, or it's really complicated. It seems to me somewhere in between. :-)

Comment: I think it's pretty simple and I'm disappointed I didn't figure it out. Although, the sizes of values I'm actually dealing with are considerable, which does make it a little more complicated to compute so maybe it is in between. Thank you!